# Endpoint doesn't support BlobStorageEvents or softdelete exception

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, linked-service

While trying to do a DataPreview or debug a pipeline, i am getting the below error stating "endpoint doesn't support blobstorage events or soft delete"

I do not want to disable the soft delete

[image: linked service details]

[image: error details]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-errors#error-code-df-blob-functionnotsupport) Azure Blob Storage events, soft delete or automatic snapshot are not supported in data flows if the Azure Blob Storage linked service is created with service principal or managed identity authentication.

The recommendation is to disable Azure Blob Storage events, soft delete or automatic snapshot feature on the Azure Blob account, or use key authentication to create the linked service. Given that you do not want to lose the soft delete, you'd need to use key authentication in the setup of the linked service.

Comment: Thank you ..Using key authentication resolved the issue..Its so frustrating to see that one team at microsoft develops something and another team doesn't support it.Using key everytime ideally shouldn't be a good cause if many people are working with the same linked service.

Comment: could you please explain what is "key authentication" here, do you mean Access Key Auth ?